# mapstruct update mapping one-to-many relationship by merging child dto with existing child entities

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

I have two entities with a one-to-many relationship, as follow:

```
public class ParentEntity {

   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private List<ChildEntity> children;

   //getters/setters

}

public class ChildEntity {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private ParentEntity myParent;

    private String notMappedField1;
    private Long notMappedField2;

    //getters/setters

}
```

And the DTOs

```
public class ParentDTO {

       private Long id;
       private String name;
       private List<ChildDto> children;

       //getters/setters

    }

    public class ChildDto {

        private Long id;
        private String name;
        private ParentDto myParent;

        //getters/setters

    }
```

With Mapstruct annotations I created two mappers, one for each entity:

```
   @Mapper(componentModel = "cdi", uses = {ChildMapper.class})
   public interface ParentMapper {      
       ParentDto toDto(ParentEntity entity);     
       ParentEntity toEntity(ParentDto s);      
       ParentEntity toEntity(ParentDto s, @MappingTarget ParentEntity entity);           
   }

   @Mapper(componentModel = "cdi")
   public interface ChildMapper {

       ChildDto toDto(ChildEntity entity);

       @Mapping(target = "myParent", ignore = true)
       ChildEntity toEntity(ChildDto s);

       @InheritConfiguration
       ChildEntity toEntity(ChildDto s, @MappingTarget ChildEntity entity);

   }
```

The generated parent mapper is the following:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ParentMapperImpl implements ParentMapper {

    @Inject
    private ChildMapper childMapper;

    @Override
    public ParentDto toDto(ParentEntity entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        ParentDto parentDto = new ParentDto();

        parentDto.setId( entity.getId() );
        parentDto.setName( entity.getName() );
        parentDto.setChildren( childEntityListToChildDtoList( entity.getChildren() ) );

        return parentDto;
    }

    @Override
    public ParentEntity toEntity(ParentDto s) {
        if ( s == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        ParentEntity parentEntity = new ParentEntity();

        parentEntity.setId( s.getId() );
        parentEntity.setName( s.getName() );
        parentEntity.setChildren( childDtoListToChildEntityList( s.getChildren() ) );

        return parentEntity;
    }

    @Override
    public ParentEntity toEntity(ParentDto s, ParentEntity entity) {
        if ( s == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        entity.setId( s.getId() );
        entity.setName( s.getName() );
        if ( entity.getChildren() != null ) {
            List<ChildEntity> list = childDtoListToChildEntityList( s.getChildren() );
            if ( list != null ) {
                entity.getChildren().clear();
                entity.getChildren().addAll( list );
            }
            else {
                entity.setChildren( null );
            }
        }
        else {
            List<ChildEntity> list = childDtoListToChildEntityList( s.getChildren() );
            if ( list != null ) {
                entity.setChildren( list );
            }
        }

        return entity;
    }

    protected List<ChildDto> childEntityListToChildDtoList(List<ChildEntity> list) {
        if ( list == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<ChildDto> list1 = new ArrayList<ChildDto>( list.size() );
        for ( ChildEntity childEntity : list ) {
            list1.add( childMapper.toDto( childEntity ) );
        }

        return list1;
    }

    protected List<ChildEntity> childDtoListToChildEntityList(List<ChildDto> list) {
        if ( list == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<ChildEntity> list1 = new ArrayList<ChildEntity>( list.size() );
        for ( ChildDto childDto : list ) {
            list1.add( childMapper.toEntity( childDto ) );
        }

        return list1;
    }
}
```

But when the `ParentMapper.toEntity(ParentDto s, ParentEntity entity)` is called, 
on the child mapper is called `ChildMapper.toEntity(ChildDto s)`.

Instead I would like the following child mapper method `ChildMapper.toEntity(ChildDto s, ChildEntity entity)` to be called, 
to merge the existing children entities (let's say we have other fields on the 
child entities that are not present in the Dto that we don't want to lose).
The desired result is the following, or something equivalent:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ParentMapperImpl implements ParentMapper {

      ...

      @Override
      public ParentEntity toEntity(ParentDto s, ParentEntity entity) {
          if (s == null) {
              return null;
          }

          entity.setId(s.getId());
          entity.setName(s.getName());
          if (entity.getChildren() != null) {
              List<ChildEntity> list = childDtoListToChildEntityList(s.getChildren(), entity.getChildren());
              if (list != null) {
                  entity.getChildren().clear();
                  entity.getChildren().addAll(list);
              } else {
                  entity.setChildren(null);
              }
          } else {
              List<ChildEntity> list = childDtoListToChildEntityList(s.getChildren());
              if (list != null) {
                  entity.setChildren(list);
              }
          }

          return entity;
      }

      ...

      protected List<ChildEntity> childDtoListToChildEntityList(List<ChildDto> list, List<ChildEntity> entities) {
          if (list == null) {
              return null;
          }


          final List<ChildEntity> list1 = new ArrayList<ChildEntity>(list.size());
          for (ChildEntity entity : entities) {
              Optional<ChildEntity> optional = findEntity(entity.getId(), list);
              if (optional.isPresent()) {
                  list1.add(childMapper.toEntity(optional.get(), entity));
              }
          }

          list1.addAll(
                  list.stream()
                          .filter(dto -> dto.getId() == null)
                          .map(dto -> childMapper.toEntity(dto))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList())
          );


          return list1;
      }

      private Optional<ChildEntity> findEntity(Long id, List<ChildDto> list) {
          return list.stream().filter(dto -> dto.getId().equals(id)).findAny();
      }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

My porpouse is to perform the update of one-to-many entities relationship, by merging existing children entities, let's say we have other fields on the children entities that are not present in the Dto that we don't want to lose.

I have two entities with a one-to-many relationship, as follow:

```
public class ParentEntity {

   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private List<ChildEntity> children;

   //getters/setters

}

public class ChildEntity {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private ParentEntity myParent;

    private String notMappedField1;
    private Long notMappedField2;

    //getters/setters

}
```

And the DTOs

```
public class ParentDTO {

       private Long id;
       private String name;
       private List<ChildDto> children;

       //getters/setters

    }

    public class ChildDto {

        private Long id;
        private String name;
        private ParentDto myParent;

        //getters/setters

    }
```

With Mapstruct annotations I created two mappers, one for each entity:

```
   @Mapper(componentModel = "cdi", uses = {ChildMapper.class})
   public interface ParentMapper {      
       ParentDto toDto(ParentEntity entity);     
       ParentEntity toEntity(ParentDto s);      
       ParentEntity toEntity(ParentDto s, @MappingTarget ParentEntity entity);           
   }

   @Mapper(componentModel = "cdi")
   public interface ChildMapper {

       ChildDto toDto(ChildEntity entity);

       @Mapping(target = "myParent", ignore = true)
       ChildEntity toEntity(ChildDto s);

       @InheritConfiguration
       ChildEntity toEntity(ChildDto s, @MappingTarget ChildEntity entity);

   }
```

The generated parent mapper is the following:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ParentMapperImpl implements ParentMapper {

    @Inject
    private ChildMapper childMapper;

    @Override
    public ParentDto toDto(ParentEntity entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        ParentDto parentDto = new ParentDto();

        parentDto.setId( entity.getId() );
        parentDto.setName( entity.getName() );
        parentDto.setChildren( childEntityListToChildDtoList( entity.getChildren() ) );

        return parentDto;
    }

    @Override
    public ParentEntity toEntity(ParentDto s) {
        if ( s == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        ParentEntity parentEntity = new ParentEntity();

        parentEntity.setId( s.getId() );
        parentEntity.setName( s.getName() );
        parentEntity.setChildren( childDtoListToChildEntityList( s.getChildren() ) );

        return parentEntity;
    }

    @Override
    public ParentEntity toEntity(ParentDto s, ParentEntity entity) {
        if ( s == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        entity.setId( s.getId() );
        entity.setName( s.getName() );
        if ( entity.getChildren() != null ) {
            List<ChildEntity> list = childDtoListToChildEntityList( s.getChildren() );
            if ( list != null ) {
                entity.getChildren().clear();
                entity.getChildren().addAll( list );
            }
            else {
                entity.setChildren( null );
            }
        }
        else {
            List<ChildEntity> list = childDtoListToChildEntityList( s.getChildren() );
            if ( list != null ) {
                entity.setChildren( list );
            }
        }

        return entity;
    }

    protected List<ChildDto> childEntityListToChildDtoList(List<ChildEntity> list) {
        if ( list == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<ChildDto> list1 = new ArrayList<ChildDto>( list.size() );
        for ( ChildEntity childEntity : list ) {
            list1.add( childMapper.toDto( childEntity ) );
        }

        return list1;
    }

    protected List<ChildEntity> childDtoListToChildEntityList(List<ChildDto> list) {
        if ( list == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<ChildEntity> list1 = new ArrayList<ChildEntity>( list.size() );
        for ( ChildDto childDto : list ) {
            list1.add( childMapper.toEntity( childDto ) );
        }

        return list1;
    }
}
```

A first solution that came up to my mind was to perform the update of children entities list by merging the child dto list and the children entities list, so I tought that when the `ParentMapper.toEntity(ParentDto s, ParentEntity entity)` is called, the child mapper method `ChildMapper.toEntity(ChildDto s, ChildEntity entity)` has to be called, to merge the existing children entities, and not this one `ChildMapper.toEntity(ChildDto s)`.
So the result could be the following, or something equivalent:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ParentMapperImpl implements ParentMapper {

      ...

      @Override
      public ParentEntity toEntity(ParentDto s, ParentEntity entity) {
          if (s == null) {
              return null;
          }

          entity.setId(s.getId());
          entity.setName(s.getName());
          if (entity.getChildren() != null) {
              List<ChildEntity> list = childDtoListToChildEntityList(s.getChildren(), entity.getChildren());
              if (list != null) {
                  entity.getChildren().clear();
                  entity.getChildren().addAll(list);
              } else {
                  entity.setChildren(null);
              }
          } else {
              List<ChildEntity> list = childDtoListToChildEntityList(s.getChildren());
              if (list != null) {
                  entity.setChildren(list);
              }
          }

          return entity;
      }

      ...

      protected List<ChildEntity> childDtoListToChildEntityList(List<ChildDto> list, List<ChildEntity> entities) {
          if (list == null) {
              return null;
          }


          final List<ChildEntity> list1 = new ArrayList<ChildEntity>(list.size());
          for (ChildEntity entity : entities) {
              Optional<ChildEntity> optional = findEntity(entity.getId(), list);
              if (optional.isPresent()) {
                  list1.add(childMapper.toEntity(optional.get(), entity));
              }
          }

          list1.addAll(
                  list.stream()
                          .filter(dto -> dto.getId() == null)
                          .map(dto -> childMapper.toEntity(dto))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList())
          );


          return list1;
      }

      private Optional<ChildEntity> findEntity(Long id, List<ChildDto> list) {
          return list.stream().filter(dto -> dto.getId().equals(id)).findAny();
      }

}
```

Is this feasible with Mapstruct?
Is there another way to update children relationship with Mapstruct?

Comment: Isn't this a bit different that what you asked? You were asking for updating a collection of `ChildEntity`. This answer is about object factories. (maybe I misunderstood the question)

Comment: As stated in the title, my porpouse was to merge child entities, the first solution that came up to my mind was by merging child entities list, perhaps my proposed solution was misleading, actually what I would was something that lead to the same result, I edit the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. There is already an open issue for this. Have a look at [487](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/487).

It is not that trivial to perform a merge of 2 lists. It requires for MapStruct to know how to generate that find method.